# How do I plot values in an array vs the number of times those values appear in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a set of ages (over 10000 of them) and I want to plot a graph with the age from 20 to 100 on the x axis and then the number of times each of those ages appears in the data on the y axis. I have tried several ways to do this and I can't figure it out. I also have some other data which requires me to plot values vs how many times they occur so any advice on how to do this would be much appreciated.

I'm quite new to Matlab so it would be great if you could explain how things in your answer work rather than just typing out some code.

Thanks.

EDIT:

So I typed histogram(Age, 80) because as I understand that will plot the values in Age on a histogram split up into 80 bars (1 for each age). Instead I get this:

[image]

The bars aren't aligned and it's clearly not 1 per age nor has it plotted the number of times each age occurs on the y axis.

Comment: Check out [`hist`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html), or [`histogram`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) in recent Matlab versions

Comment: Yeh I have no idea how to make that function do what I want. I've tried several things and it doesn't work.

Comment: Post a minimal example with runnable code and tell where you got stuck so we can help

Comment: I have added what I typed into the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `histogram()`, and that's correct.
Let's see with an example.

I extract 100 ages between 20 and 100:

```
ages=randsample([20:100],100,true);
```

Now I call `histogram()` in this manner:

```
h=histogram(ages,[20:100]);
```

where `h` is an *histogram object* and this will also show the following plot:

[image]

However, this might look easy due to the fact that my ages vector is in range 20:100, so it will not contain any other values. If your vector, as instead, contains also ages not in range 20:100, you can specify the additional option `'BinLimits'` as third input in `histogram()` like this:

```
h=histogram(ages,length([20:100]),'BinLimits',[20:100]);
```

and this option plots a histogram using the values in `ages` that fall between 20 and 100 inclusive.

*Note*: by inspecting `h` you can actually see and/or edit some proprieties of your histogram. An attribute (field) of such object you might be interested to is *Values*. This is a vector of length 80 (in our case, since we work with 80 bins) in which the i-th element is the number of items is the i-th bin. This will help you count the occurrences (just in case you need them to go on with your analysis).

Comment: The bars aren't aligned properly though. And it can't be correct because  using that equation show that there aren't any ages of 31, but there are in the data. I just want a bar for the number of people age 20, 21, 22, ... , 100 with the height being how many people are of that age.

Comment: Never mind I fixed it by doing histogram(Age,[20:1:100]) to specify I wanted widths of 1.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, my bad. I was using `hist()` in a previous example but then I realized you were using `histogram()` so I edited my answer but I forgot to remove the `length()` function!

Answer (score 0):

Like Luis said in comments, `hist` is the way to go. You should specify bin edges, rather than the number of bins:

```
ages = randi([20 100], [1 10000]);
hist(ages, [20:100])
```

Is this what you were looking for?